# what library to use for time comparison

Tags: java

I've got some objects which contain `date` fields. Date field - simple `java.util.Date` class.

So I've been wondering whether I should use some library(like `joda`) for fields comparison or standard methods(like `before` or `after`) of `java.util.Date` class are enough?

P.S. I specifically interested in range comparison - whether date is in some range (not less than some date and not bigger than).

Comment: Date is deprecated, use Calendar or JodaTime or Java 8's Time API.

Comment: @Zhuinden: No, `Date` is not deprecated. It's a horrible API, but it's not deprecated.

Comment: You need to specify the requirements more carefully. If you're really talking about *dates* (rather than instances of time), then using `LocalDate` from either Joda Time or Java 8 would be appropriate. Also, it would help if you'd say what version of Java you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have specific requirements, stick to the standard.

Comment: Specific requirements - date range comparison (whether date is in the specific range)

Comment: I think that a simple date.before(date1) && date.after(date2) with nullity checking should be enough. If usage is recurrent, just define a helper  method.